# Background push notifications iOS Firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a flutter iOS app using firebase, but notifications are not received in the background. If firebase notifications are sent while the app is in the background, the notification is not received, but when the app is opened, the notification is displayed (received).

I have used the same code on a previous app and has worked perfectly so I'm not sure what the issue is.

I have turned on background modes and push notifications in xcode. I have given the apns in firebase.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks

This is my Code

```
Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message){
  print("Background Message Handler");
  print("Background Message: $message");

  return Future<void>.value();
}

class PushMessagingExample extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PushMessagingExampleState createState() => _PushMessagingExampleState();
}
class _PushMessagingExampleState extends State<PushMessagingExample> {
  String _homeScreenText = "Waiting for token...";
  String _messageText = "Waiting for message...";
final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        setState(() {
          _messageText = "Push Messaging message: $message";
        });
        showNotification();
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },

      onBackgroundMessage: myBackgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        setState(() {
          _messageText = "Push Messaging message: $message";
        });
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        setState(() {
          _messageText = "Push Messaging message: $message";
        });
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
    _firebaseMessaging.requestNotificationPermissions(
        const IosNotificationSettings(sound: true, badge: true, alert: true));
    _firebaseMessaging.onIosSettingsRegistered
        .listen((IosNotificationSettings settings) {
      print("Settings registered: $settings");
    });
    
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings,
        selectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    
    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      print("Token:$token");
    });

    _firebaseMessaging.getToken().then((String token) {
      assert(token != null);
      setState(() {
        _homeScreenText = "Push Messaging token: $token";
      });
      print(_homeScreenText);
    });
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) {
    debugPrint("payload : $payload");
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) => new AlertDialog(
        title: new Text('Notification'),
        content: new Text('$payload'),
      ),
    );
  }


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Push Messaging Demo'),
        ),
        body: Material(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text(_homeScreenText),
              ),
              Row(children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: Text(_messageText),
                ),
              ])
            ],
),
        ));
  }

  showNotification() async {
    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel NAME', 'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
        priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max);
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
        0, 'New Video is out', 'Hello notif body', platform,
        payload: 'This is the notification body');
  }

}
void main() {
  runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      home: PushMessagingExample(),
    ),
  );
}
```

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>code_notif_test</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fetch</string>
        <string>processing</string>
        <string>remote-notification</string>
    </array>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Need more details !!

Comment: What details would you like to know I am happy to provide them for you

Comment: Debug for example ?

Comment: Details about the conf
Info.plist

Comment: add  FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled: false in Info.plist

Comment: @Fatimaayaa Thanks for the comment but I have already tried this and no success

Comment: you have to provide your code

Comment: @Fatimaayaa Thank you for your response, I have added the code in the post

Comment: @BakhoucheAkram I have added the info.plist in the post